# Doubt regarding characteristic curves for Quasi-linear PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider a quasi-linear first order PDE which is of the form $a(x,y,u)u_x+b(x,y,u)u_y=c(x,y,u)$. Where we consider $a,b,c$ to be smooth. Now, for many cases I've observed that through a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ more than one base curves ( these are projections of characteristic curves of the quasi linear PDE to $x-y$ plane) can pass. But doesn't this contradicts the Cauchy-Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem of ODEs? Why is it not the case?

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, I think you are talking about shocks, where multiple characteristics cross each other. If so, you might want to read [this](https://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2011/Spring/physics221a/LECTURES/CH11_SHOCKS.pdf) (page 5 onwards).

Comment: @mattos i'm not sure if the question is misleading. I'm saying that if through a point in x-y plane more than one base curves passes does it contradict the existence and uniqueness theorem of ODE. For base curves, they arise from the following ODEs $\frac{dx}{dt}=a(x,y,u), \frac{dy}{dt}=b(x,y,u)$, now i'm asking if they intersect (they does for QL PDE) doesn't that contradict E and U theorems?